# How can I build the speech to text android app for offline?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I have built a simple voice recognition android app in android studio.

It works fine online, but requires WIFI.

I want to know a way to use the android voice recognition engine directly, anyway the android `<S Voice>` app works well in offline.

I use the Samsung galaxy 5s now.

Comment: Android voice recognition does not work without internet access because the recognition is done on Google servers, not on the device.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the place to request a crash-course or tutorial on how to achieve something. If you have a specific programming problem, then please rephrase your question to reflect that. See [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to find out how to ask the right type of question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have built the android app for voice recognition based on this [tutorial] (http://www.truiton.com/2014/06/android-speech-recognition-without-dialog-custom-activity). It is very simple. But at first I didn't know the fact that I can't use this app for offline.  So I have to develop the my own engine for it?  Or  How can I use the engine inside the device?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot access google's inbuilt speech to text recognition offline. But if you want to use it you do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            "Speak Now");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Not supported",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. so you are sure that this code will be implemented successfully without wifi?   In my phone, I cant get any result without internet.